# Remove initial directives from preprocessor output

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I have the following in `test.c`:

```
#if 1
foo boo bar
#endif
```

Then I run `gcc` like this:

```
gcc -E test.c -o test.pp
```

This is the `test.pp` output:

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"

foo boo bar
```

Is there a way to remove these `# [something]` directives and let only (in this case) `foo boo bar` only by using gcc flags? I mean, I would like that the preprocessor output would be only `foo boo bar` in this case.

Comment: Like option [-P](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-P)?

Comment: @ssbssa might you want to post that as an answer?